# Expectation of Integrals of Brownian Motion

Tags: probability, brownian-motion

Hello I am not a native english speaker so please let me know if something does not make sense. I am interested in computing the following:

$$E\int_0^T(B_s(\omega,t))^4dt$$

Or at least showing it is finite because I want to prove that $(B_s(\omega,t))^2\in\mathcal H[0,T]$. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint** Apply Tonelli's theorem and use that $\mathbb{E}(B_t^4)=3t^2$ as $B_t$ is Gaussian with mean $0$ and variance $t$.

---

**Remark** Please note that the expression $B_s(\omega,t)$ does not make sense at all. The Brownian motion depends on the time (usually denoted by $t$) and the "random" $\omega$. So, in your case, it should read

$$\mathbb{E} \int_0^T B_t^4 \, dt \qquad \text{or} \qquad \mathbb{E}\int_0^T B(t)^4 \, dt$$

or

$$\int\!\!\! \int_0^T B_t(\omega)^4 \, dt \, d\mathbb{P}(\omega) \qquad \text{or} \int\!\!\! \int_0^T B(t,\omega)^4 \, dt \, d\mathbb{P}(\omega)$$

(Mind that $\mathbb{E}X = \int X(\omega) \, d\mathbb{P}(\omega)$; it is not correct to write $\mathbb{E}X(\omega)$ for some random variable $X$.)

Comment: Yes you are right I was so distracted by trying to get the formatting right I made a notational error! I did indeed mean $\mathbb{E} \int_0^T B_t(\omega)^4dt$. So then we would have that $\mathbb{E} \int_0^T B_t(\omega)^4dt = \int_0^T 3t^2dt = T^3$, correct? I have a related question but it is probably not important enough to create a separate thread for: now that we have that the variation of $B_s^2$ is bounded, how would one evaluate the integral $\int_0^tB_s^2dB_s$? I am trying to work through this example to try to understand Ito integration but I do not know how to proceed.

Comment: Actually the first formulas (the ones with $\omega$s) are not written correctly either. If one insists on inserting $\omega$s (which is most of the time unnecessary), then one should use the formatting $$\int_\Omega X(\omega)\mathrm dP(\omega).$$

Comment: OP: Re your comment, note that $\displaystyle\int B_s^2dB_s$ is an altogether different beast from $\displaystyle\int B_s^4ds$.

Comment: Hmm I see. So would it be proper to write $\int_0^tB_s^2(\omega)dB_s(\omega)$? Or should I just omit the omega entirely? Yes it is different but the relation between them was that (I think) I need that $\mathbb{E} \int_0^TB_s^4dB_s$ is finite in order to evaluate $\int_0^TB_s^2dB_s$.
Edit: I believe this is related to the Ito isometry?

Comment: @Inneedofhelp The fact that $$\mathbb{E} \left( \int_0^T B_t^4 \,  dt \right)<\infty$$ (and that $(t,\omega) \mapsto B(t,\omega)^4$ is progressively measurable) ensures that $$\int_0^t B_s^2 \, dB_s$$ is well-defined. But, as Did already pointed out, this integral is totally different from $\int B_s^4 \, ds$, because one is a stochastic intergal and the other one a (pathwise) Riemann integral.

Comment: @Did Yes, I agree with you that the first ones (with $\omega$) are not correct either, but there are a several authors who stick with this notation.

Comment: I am surprised, because the notation $E(X(\omega))$, say, is inconsistent as $\displaystyle\int f(x)$ would be. Which authors are you alluding to? (+1 for the answer, it is good to have somebody able to answer stochastic integration questions on the site.)

Comment: @Did Well, I don't remember the name of the authors, but I have seen it several times. As you can imagine, I prefer more rigorous books... (And thanks for your upvote; I try my best.)

Comment: Thank you both for your help and as per your suggestion I have posted a separate question about evaluating $\int_0^tB_s^2dB_s$